Installing Debug Symbol Packages for an Old Release
I am using Lunar, which at the time of writing is archived. My main sources.list entries are pointing to http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu. I want to fetch debug symbols for applications as the debuginfod system is just not working for me. I see the files under http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists.old/ but I don't know how I can point apt there to use these. Or if the debug packages are hosted elsewhere on the archives, but have tried a few things and apt update 404s.
Is there a way I can point apt towards the debug symbol repositories for a version that is EOL?
Thanks

Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

I understand that Canonical can't devote time to providing support for EOL releases, but many people have used old-releases for a long time to buy a bit more grace time to upgrade. I will tread on many toes and expend time I don't have if I force all our systems up every six months like clockwork, and I will do exactly the same if I refuse people newer packages by sticking to LTS. Migrations take time because lots breaks. The packages are still hosted on the server. I'm not sure on the reason for an archive if it's then a brick wall of not supported and I can't even ask a question about it.
